# Meaning of flags in the class Wikipedia Edit Event

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

The Wikipedia Edit Event class has 6 flags
1. isBotEdit
2. isMinor
3. isNew
4. isSpecial
5. isTalk
6. isUnpatrolled
There is no description written in the official link [Official WikipediaEditEvent Link](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/wikiedits/WikipediaEditEvent.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information content of the Wikipedia change stream is described in https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Recent_changes:

- isMinor indicates that the user marked the edit "minor". Only logged in users can mark edits minor, to avoid abuse.
- isNew indicates that the page is "new", i.e., previously did not exist. It is possible for a change to possess both the "minor" and "new" indicators; this is typically used for new redirects.
- isBot indicates that the edit is made by a bot (an account with bot flag), or that the edit is hidden by an administrator.
- isUnpatrolled indicates that the page is unpatrolled. For more information see [the Help topic Patrolled Edit](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Patrolled_edit).

[Special pages](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Special_page) and [Talk pages](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Talk_page) are specific kinds of Wikipedia pages.